# 100% height links in inline navigation with varying <li> heights

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

First time caller, long time listener...

I'm trying to set up the styles for horizontal tab-looking navigation. However, in its usage I need it to accommodate links of varying lengths that may make any li wrap  to multiple lines. But when it does, the other links don't fill 100% height.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rothgarr/qL47V/

As you can see, link two is taller and it wraps - so links one, three and four don't fill that space. And in this example one of the links wraps to two lines, but in reality they may wrap to three or four, etc. so I can't define a height. How do I get all the other links to fill that space? (not just the background color)

Here's my stripped down html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">This is item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is item two it's very long</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is item three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is item four</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's my stripped down css:

```
ul, li {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;}

ul {
border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
overflow: hidden;}

li {
float: left;
width: 120px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: center;}

a {
display: block;
background-color: #ccc; }
```

I tried the following: As many combinations of floats and inline-block as I could think of / Displaying the ul as a table and each li as a table-cell / Using relative and absolute positioning to try to fill each space

Other notes: As I mentioned above, I can't define a height since I don't know how many lines there will be / I pretty sure I have to support *sigh* IE8

Any ideas? Bonus points: How do I get the shorter links to align to bottom?

Comment: Apparently this can be done using some jquery, see this forked example of my original jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rothgarr/LWQ7G/1/ . I didn't realize a script was needed to accomplish this and was hoping this could be done strictly with css...

Answer (score 3):

## Pure CSS solution

If you're feeeling adventurous, you can always try CSS flexbox: it is designed specifically for layouts like this that are hard to achieve in *conventional* CSS methods. However, it does not work in older browsers, only in modern ones.

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: #ccc; 
}
```

The explanation behind my code:

- Set `<ul>` to display flex, and stretch all children vertically (`align-items: stretch`)
- Set `<li>` to display flex, too — so that we can force it's inner child to stretch vertically, too.
- Set `<a>` to `flex: 1 1 auto`, such that it will grow and shrink automagically. Width can be `auto` or `100%`, it does not matter in this case.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qL47V/7/

## JS-based solution

You can also use a JS-based solution (I have used jQuery, but you can of course use other libraries). The strategy is simple:

1. Get the original height of links in the list
2. Find the maximum value, and assigns it to all links

This is rather straight forward when writing in jQuery:

```
var heights = [];
$('ul a').each(function() {
    heights.push($(this).height());
}).height(Math.max.apply(Math,heights));
```

However, you should take note that these few lines of script will have to be re-run whenever the dimensions of the links are changed such that it will affect the height.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qL47V/9/

Comment: This is really interesting. I gave it +1 since it's purely css. However, I absolutely need this to work in IE9 (which apparently doesn't support this). And I also need IE8 support...

Comment: If you have to support older browsers, the flexbox solution is out — you'll either have to resort to table-based styling (`display: table`) or a JS-based solution.

Comment: @Rothgarr Added a simple JS-based solution, if you're looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say you want the links to fill that space, you mean that you want the background to fill the entire space. That being said, you can do that with the following:

```
ul {
  display: table;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #ccc;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qL47V/3/

As you can see, if you put the background on the list item (which is set to `display: table-cell`) it will then fill the whole space.

There may be nicer ways to do this (I personally hate styling things as tables), but this will get you where you need to go.

Comment: This is close, but per the original I need the actual links to fill that space, not just the background color. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qL47V/8/)

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;           /* Make all <li> have same height */
    width: 120px;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff; /* Fake right-margin */
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc; 
    vertical-align: bottom;        /* Align anchors to bottom */
    overflow: hidden;              /* Hide overflow caused by huge anchors */
}
a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100000px;         /* Make anchors huge to be sure 
                                      they cover <li> completely */
    margin-top: -100000px;         /* Place them correctly */
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, the link isn't filling the entire height.

Comment: @Rothgarr Oh, I didn't know they should. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You're in the right track with `a {display: block;}`. In addition to that, you need to switch the padding from `li` to `li a` (just using `a` would apply it all links on the page rather than just the ones in the list):

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This will make the properties of `a` fill the parent `li` element.

As for your second request, you **cannot** use `vertical-align` with **block level** elements. That is why the other answers here have set the `display` style to `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`. The data is *not* tabular, so keep in mind tables are therefore not the best way to achieve what you want. Also keep in mind that this method might nto work with IE8. However, sometimes practically trumps standards compliance, so it's up to you to achieve what you want.

**[Douglas Heriot](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)** has written an extensive blog post on how to achieve vertical alignment in block-level elements, if you've the time and inclination to read through it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but the heights of the different "tabs" are still different and would be even moreso if the longest link goes to three or more lines. And the secondary request is just that, secondary -- I can live without that if I can get the links to fill that entire height.

Comment: @Rothgarr I'm working on it at the moment, it's proving tricky. As for the secondary request, I think you may need to use JS to achieve that, since even getting an `a` to fill a parent `li` won't work, due to each `li` being separate. You'd have to set all `li`s to take 100% height of the parent div.

Comment: I came across a jquery solution (http://jsfiddle.net/Rothgarr/LWQ7G/1/) -- I didn't realize at the time that this was needed. If you know of a css-only way to accomplish this I'm all ears!

Comment: @Rothgarr The best alternative I think would be to use `flexbox`, but alas I don't have the time to tinker out a solution. It's worth looking into, though, if you've the time!